# Не работает стиль для button в android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Мне нужно чтобы у button был определенный стиль, я создал для этого отдельный xml файл, но почему-то button свой стиль не меняет.
Я попробовал разный код, но результат один и тот же, я не знаю что делать уже

Вот код фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartFragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="161dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот код стиля для button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#3DE3E3" />

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="#4C190B" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно у вас material design тема, в ней некоторые view в xml (`<Button />`  `<TextView/>` и другие) заменяются на Material версии, которые игнорят `android:background` атрибут.

У MaterialButton есть множество своих атрибутов для настройки стиля

`<solid android:color="#3DE3E3" />` можно заменить на `android:backgroundTint="#3DE3E3"`

```
<stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="#4C190B" />
```

на

```
app:strokeWidth="10dp"
app:strokeColor="#4C190B"
```

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="161dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Button"

        android:backgroundTint="#3DE3E3"
        app:strokeWidth="10dp"
        app:strokeColor="#4C190B"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword" />
```

Либо можно заменить тему или использовать `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton/>`